# Custom Header Style

Tags: pdftex, header-footer

I want to make this header style, any help?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: `fancyhdr`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I tried these commands, and they worked like a charm (with some personal preferences). You can tweak them until you get the result you want.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{Chapter 
\begin{Large}
    \triangleleft
\end{Large} \thepage }
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage
\begin{Large}
    \triangleright
\end{Large} Section}
```